# change arp refresh rate (package sending rate)

Tags: linux, networking, arp

i have a measurement setup where i want to trigger an oscilloscope base on a network package arriving. I have good results for a few seconds but somewhere between 20s and 40s i get a wrong trigger. My research showed that this could come from the arp packages send from the device. I tried to disable the arp sending but then the whole network went down. Now i'm trying to find a solution where i change the rate at which the arp packets are send without success. So i'm asking you if you know a way to either disable or send as few arp request as possible.

For your information i'm working on a Linux machine. Any help would be appreciated.

I allready tried:

```
#ip link set arp off dev eth0 <--- results in network down
```

changing the values for:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_interval
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_stale_time
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_interval
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_timeout
```

with no success

Thx draufunddran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Disabling ARP on your machine will eventually cause other nodes on the network to stop sending packets to your machine (that is why your network appears to go down).

If you want to completely disable ARP packets on your network, you will need to manually program ARP tables on other nodes on your LAN (subnet) so that they know how to map your host's IP to a MAC address to send to on the LAN. This is a difficult thing to do if even possible since some nodes on your network may not offer the ability to program their ARP tables manually.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was going with disabling ARP. I couldn't connect anymore but the packets were still coming and i could measure them on the osciloscope. After the reboot, everything was working corectly again.